# how to change location of geom_stats in ggcyto plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioconductor

I am trying to move the position of the annotation output of `geom_stats()` so that is does not cover the plot. I want it towards the top right corner and I tried passing a `c(0.5, 1)` to the `adjust` argument, but it doesn't work. I could continue to guess the `Y` value; `c(0.5, Y)` and it would work for some plots, but I have about 100 plots that will be strung together in a `arrangeGrob` object. So, some of the plots would have the location "correct" but others would not show up because the `Y` is not a global y-axis value for all. I tried adding `abs=TRUE` as mentioned in here: [link 1](https://github.com/RGLab/ggcyto/issues/73), but I get a warning that that argument does not exist. This [link 2](https://bioconductor.statistik.tu-dortmund.de/packages/3.8/bioc/vignettes/ggcyto/inst/doc/ggcyto.GatingSet.html) didn't help either. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
library(flowCore)
library(flowWorkspace)
library(ggcyto)
data(GvHD)
fs <- GvHD[1:4]
param <- "FL2-A"
g <- openCyto::gate_flowclust_2d(fs[[1]], xChannel = "FSC-H", yChannel = "SSC-H", K = 3, target = c(450, 300), quantile=0.8)
gs_sub <- Subset(fs[1], g)
gs <- GatingSet(gs_sub)
g_ <- openCyto:::.mindensity(gs@data[[1]], channels = param)

ggcyto(gs@data[[1]], aes(x = !!param)) +
  geom_histogram(stat = "bin", bins = 100) +
  geom_gate(g_) +
  geom_stats(size = 8,
             adjust = c(1, 0.5),
             label.padding = unit(0.05, "lines"))
```

Here is my R `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggcyto_1.14.1            ncdfFlow_2.32.0          BH_1.75.0-0              RcppArmadillo_0.10.4.0.0 ggplot2_3.3.3            flowWorkspace_3.34.1     flowCore_1.52.1
```

Comment: i added `sessionInfo`. I am using R 3.6.0 bc it uses legacy code that has to use that version.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your example, `Error: no slot of name "data" for this object of class "GatingSet"`. You're using really old versions of flowCore and flowWorkspace. I don't see how anyone could recreate your particular old versions to be able to reproduce the issue. It might be time to deal with the legacy code.

Comment: hi Ian, thanks for trying. Unfortunately, changing the legacy code is above me, it is the company's code.